# how does facebook opens short popups for photos and other short messages and remains on same page

Tags: ajax, facebook

While using facebook, when we click on some links, a small box appears in front of us initially showing LOADING and then loads the content e.g. photos, show more etc.
Are they using AJAX to do so!

Please help me in this.
Thanx in advance...!

Answer (score 2):

You might get the same effect using AJAX.

Also look here: http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/